# infinite scroll from remote server with angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic angular project. There's a section where I'm implementing infinite scroll, and when I scroll to the bottom I see the data  showing up.

What I've realized is the data somehow pre-populates and hides, waiting to come up when the user reaches the bottom of the page. Because no call is made to the server to load the other feeds, I'm displaying 5 records at a time.

From the php script, I've converted to a json. I have 60 rows, and from the chrome console I read the json length to be 60, meaning all the 60 rows are loaded up were the data is pre-populated already.

Is there a way I can show 5 records at a time and then when the user scrolls to the bottom it passes the last id, so a call would be made to the server to load the feeds?

JS:

```
.controller('feedsctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$http.get('http://usefulsite.com/app/feeds.php').success(function(data){
       $scope.feeds= console.log(data); ;
       $scope.feeds=data;

       $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 5; // Use it with limit to in ng-repeat
$scope.addMoreItem = function(done) {
    if ($scope.feeds.length > $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay)
        $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 5; // load number of more items
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete')
});
```

php

```
SELECT * FROM users order by fname asc
```

HTML

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="false" has-bouncing="true">

        <div ng-controller="feedsctrl" class="list card has-subheader" ng-repeat="item in feeds | filter:scheduleSearch | limitTo:numberOfItemsToDisplay">

            <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img src="http://usefulsite.com/resize_image/images.php?image={{item.profile_pix}}&new_width=100&new_height=100">
                <h2><a class="names" href="#/tab/source/{{item.profile_id}}">{{item.fname}}&nbsp;{{item.lname}}</a></h2>
                <p>November 05, 1955</p>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-body">
                <img class="full-image" src="http://usefulsite.com/aoo/resize_image/images.php?image={{item.pic}}&new_width=800&new_height=800">
<p>{{item.fname}} {{item.lname}}</p>
            </div>

        </div>


        <ion-infinite-scroll

                on-infinite="addMoreItem()"
                distance="1%"
                ng-if="feeds.length > numberOfItemsToDisplay">
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: For me to under you want the user to scroll down the page and when they reach the last item the first item will show up and ect ,,,, ect,,,? ie item1,item2,item3,item1,item2,item3?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the entire data at client side than you can use the angular pagination directive for a better performing experience.

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []).controller('pagedController', function($scope) {

   $scope.numPerPage = 5;
   $scope.data = [];
  
$scope.items = [];
for (i=1;i<=60;i++) {
  $scope.items.push({ text:'item '+i});
}


  $scope.getMoreData = function () {
  $scope.data = $scope.items.slice(0, $scope.data.length + $scope.numPerPage);
  };
  
  $scope.getMoreData();
  
});

app.directive('infiniteScroll', function() {
return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];
    
    elm.on('scroll', function() {
        if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
            scope.$apply(attr.infiniteScroll);
        }
    });
};
});
```

```css
 .itemContainer
 {
width: 150px;
height: 130px; 
border: thin solid black;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
 }


 .item
 {
            
background: #f9f9f9;
font-family: verdana;
margin: 7px;
width : 110px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="pagedController">
<h1>Infinite scroll</h1>
<h4>{{items.length}} items</h4>
<div class="itemContainer" infinite-scroll="getMoreData()">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data" class="item">{{item.text}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/TJi4Um6a31fYsmVwtAmZ?p=preview

Comment: i'm kinda confused, it seems the answer is based on pagination but i'm talking about infinite scroll